# JavaScript canvas draw circle one by one using function

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

My goal is to detect where does my function crosses first the Axes X on the negative side. For that, I check from all the range at first, then I divide by two in one of the sides, depending the result.
I'd like to draw 1 by 1 all my circles. First time i got something like this:

[image]

and then i searched and tried this :

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(drawDicho(a,b));
```

And i thought it would draw each circle individually. But instead, it only draws the circle on coordinates (0,0). If i click again, it draws on it again.

[image]

¨

I've tried window.setInterval(...) but nothing happened as well.

I can recover the correct value, but I'd like to show the circles one by one and not all at the same time.
Does anyone have an idea ? Maybe I'm placing the code in the wrong place, i don't know..

@UPDATE FULL CODE:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        if(!canvas){
          alert("Impossible to recover canvas");
          return;
        }

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if(!context){
          alert("Impossible dto recover canvas context");
          return;
        }

        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';

        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;

        //draw axis Y
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(width/2, 0);
        context.lineTo(width/2, height);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();

        //draw axis X
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, height/2);
        context.lineTo(width, height/2);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();


      }


      function function1(x){
        return Math.sin(x)-(x/13);
      }

      function function2(x){
        return x/(1-Math.pow(x, 2));
      }

      function draw(func){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dx = canvas.width;
        var dy = canvas.height;
        var scale = dx/40; // echelle (nb pixels between x=0 et x=1)
        var x0 = dx/2;
        var y0 = dy/2;
        var iMax = 20;
        var x, y;
        var iMin = -20;
            context.translate(x0,y0);
      context.scale(1, -1);
            context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(-100, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      context.arc(100, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);

      for(i = -100; i<=100; i=i+0.01){
                x=i*4;
                y = scale * func(x/scale);
        context.lineTo(x, y);

          }
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();
      }

      function drawF1(){
        draw(function1);
      }

      function drawF2(){
        draw(function2);
      }

      function drawDicho(a, b){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(a, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        context.arc(b, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
      }

      function dichotomie(func){
        var a = -100;
        var b = 100;
        var fa = func(a);
        var fb = func(b);
        var delta = 0.01;

        while(Math.abs(b-a) > delta){
        //drawDicho(a,b);
          var m = (a+b)/2;
          var fm = func(m);
          if(fm * fa <= 0){
            b = m;
            fb = fm;
          }
          else{
            a = m;
            fa = fm;
          }
          window.requestAnimationFrame(drawDicho(a,b));
        }
        if(fa * fb <= 0){
          return m.toFixed(3);

        }
        else{
          return 'no 0';
        }

      }

      function $(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
      }

      function solvef1()
      {
        var result = dichotomie(function1);
        alert(result);
      }

      function solvef2(){
        var result = dichotomie(function2);
        alert(result);
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:grey">
  <p>
    <label>draw fonction: </label>
    <input type="button" name="function1" value="fonction 1" id="drawF1" onclick="drawF1()">
    <input type="button" name="function2" value="fonction 2" id="drawF2" onclick="drawF2()">
    <input type="button" name="solvef1" value="solvef1" id="solvef1" onclick="solvef1()">
    <input type="button" name="solvef2" value="solvef2" id="solvef2" onclick="solvef2()">
  </p>
    <br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">
      Message bla bla bla
    </canvas>
</body>
```

(the `dichotomie` function which calc and draw circles is used when i click on button "solve f1")

Thank you.

Comment: provide full working code with (js and html)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski i updated the question with full code !

Comment: I do call in my window.requestAnimationFrame(..), isn't that right ?

Comment: so how do I do it ? that's what I dont understand, if you could say where I have to put it in my code..

Comment: It draws circles using the variables a and b from dichotomie()

Comment: it's the line commented, below while

Comment: i call it when I click on the buttons

Comment: dichotomie is used when i click on button "solve f1"

Comment: yes, exactly what I have as values ! so i put a circle in 0, then -50, then -25, then -12.5, and so on, but one by one, like if I have a pause between them

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Comment: yes sir, even if I understand more than before, I still can't manage to draw one by one all the circles..

Comment: I give you working snippet in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your `dichotomie` in following way ( `300` is number of miliseconds between draw circles) 
(run snippet on "Full page")

```
function dichotomie(func){
    ...
    var circs=[];

    while(Math.abs(b-a) > delta){
      ...
      circs.push([a,b])
    }

    circs.map((x,i) => setTimeout(y=> drawDicho(...x),i*300) );
    ...
  }
```

In this solution we use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function(){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        if(!canvas){
          alert("Impossible to recover canvas");
          return;
        }

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if(!context){
          alert("Impossible dto recover canvas context");
          return;
        }

        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';

        var width = canvas.width;
        var height = canvas.height;

        //draw axis Y
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(width/2, 0);
        context.lineTo(width/2, height);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();

        //draw axis X
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(0, height/2);
        context.lineTo(width, height/2);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();


      }


      function function1(x){
        return Math.sin(x)-(x/13);
      }

      function function2(x){
        return x/(1-Math.pow(x, 2));
      }

      function draw(func){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var dx = canvas.width;
        var dy = canvas.height;
        var scale = dx/40; // echelle (nb pixels between x=0 et x=1)
        var x0 = dx/2;
        var y0 = dy/2;
        var iMax = 20;
        var x, y;
        var iMin = -20;
            context.translate(x0,y0);
      context.scale(1, -1);
            context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(-100, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      context.arc(100, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);

      for(i = -100; i<=100; i=i+0.01){
                x=i*4;
                y = scale * func(x/scale);
        context.lineTo(x, y);

          }
          context.closePath();
          context.stroke();
      }

      function drawF1(){
        draw(function1);
      }

      function drawF2(){
        draw(function2);
      }

      function drawDicho(a, b){
        var canvas = $('myCanvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(a, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        context.arc(b, 0, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        context.closePath();
        context.stroke();
      }

      function dichotomie(func){
        var a = -100;
        var b = 100;
        var fa = func(a);
        var fb = func(b);
        var delta = 0.01;
        var circs=[];
        
        while(Math.abs(b-a) > delta){
        //drawDicho(a,b);
          var m = (a+b)/2;
          var fm = func(m);
          
          if(fm * fa <= 0){
            b = m;
            fb = fm;
          }
          else{
            a = m;
            fa = fm;
          }
          circs.push([a,b])
        }
        console.log(circs);
        circs.map((x,i) => setTimeout(y=> drawDicho(...x),i*300) );
        
        if(fa * fb <= 0){
          return m.toFixed(3);

        }
        else{
          return 'no 0';
        }

      }

      function $(id){
        return document.getElementById(id);
      }

      function solvef1()
      {
        var result = dichotomie(function1);
        alert(result);
      }

      function solvef2(){
        var result = dichotomie(function2);
        alert(result);
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:grey">
  <p>
    <label>draw fonction: </label>
    <input type="button" name="function1" value="fonction 1" id="drawF1" onclick="drawF1()">
    <input type="button" name="function2" value="fonction 2" id="drawF2" onclick="drawF2()">
    <input type="button" name="solvef1" value="solvef1" id="solvef1" onclick="solvef1()">
    <input type="button" name="solvef2" value="solvef2" id="solvef2" onclick="solvef2()">
  </p>
    <br>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">
      Message bla bla bla
    </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Even if this will work this way, its so much NOT the way one should tackle animations…

Comment: @philipp yes - I agree - the code for calculations shoud be separated from drawing code - e.g.  function dichotomie shoud not call drawDicho function at all  but only produce data - and other procedure should take that data and pass them to drawDicho. So in architecture point of view the math-code and draw-code shoud be separated. This is hit to OP, but I will not rewrite his code in this way  because it is out of the scope of this question

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski if i copy-paste your code, it should work ? i understood it but only the circs.map((x,i) ... I mean, where does the x and i come from ?

Comment: thank you , its working ! juste a question : what does circs.map(x,i) mean ? I mean, where does those variables come from ?

Comment: @Dom I give you links in answer (above snippet but below code) - "array map" and "arrow functions" - use them

Comment: still don't get where does x and i come from, I never declare them

Comment: (x,i) => setTim... is arrow function - arguments declaration are on the left side of => , why whe declare this two variables x and i - becasue the array map takes function and to its first argument put array current array element, and on secod argument put array index (which we use to calculate time i*300 ) - read more in links i provide in answer - you need time and exercises to understand them - use google (or stack overflow to fins answers), be independent - I Will not say more because it is out of the scope of question

Answer (score 1):

`window.requestAnimationFrame` expects a function reference as parameter, such that the given function can be called a soon as the browser has finished rendering, but not faster than 60Hz.

By doing:

```
while (…) {
  …
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawDicho(a,b));
  …
}
```

you are calling `drawDicho(a,b)` right away within the `while` loop and assign the return value to `requestAnimationFrame`, which is undefined.

What you need, at least I think you do, is an animation loop like this:

```
const DELAY = 1000;

let 
  last = new Date().getTime(),
  circles = [
    [10,10],
    [100, 100],
    [10, 100]
  ]
;

//replace while () {} with the loop below,
//this way the execution is scheduled
(function loop () {
  const 
    now = new Date().getTime(),
    delta = now - last;

  if (delta >= DELAY && circles.length > 0) {
    drawCircle(...circles.shift());
    last = now;
  }


  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

})();
```

This way `loop` will be called frequently. A while loop is not an animation loop, the code is called right away. An animation loop runs with a certain »frame rate, what a while loop does not.

Comment: //do some stuff here should be what part of my code so ? i understand a bit more already with that..

Comment: I have tried to write some »dummy code« to illustrate how to turn your code into something that animates over time. But there is more to think about, speed etc. I really depends on how the animation should appear.

Comment: thank's, but I do I pass the function that I want to work with ? can i put loop(function)? im actually getting an error : loop is not defined

Comment: I've changed the method to call when I click the button to solvef1. It calls loop instead of dichotomie, is that right ? and the dichotomie function is now commented

Comment: Don't get me wrong on this, but there is really more on that. Think of a »flip-book« flipping on page to the next corresponds to rendering the scene at a given progress. Normally you need to clear the canvas and rerender everything etc.

Comment: Please see the updated code. This way each second a circle should  be drawn. That could be a simple way. Precalculate the coordinates and then draw them one by one…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190022/discussion-between-dom-and-philipp).